# Syntax error while reading csv file through python?

Tags: python, pandas

Tried multiple ways to read CSV file but it always throws syntax error. When I am not using `r` in this code, code looks like

```
import pandas  
df = pandas.read_csv(r "c:\week3data.csv")
```

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: There is a space between `r` and the string

Comment: @DeepSpace Yep, that would be it. I am flagging this as a typo question.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible the file is encoded in a different format:

Try

```
import pandas  
df = pandas.read_csv("c:\week3data.csv", ,encoding="latin-1")
```

or

```
import pandas      
df = pandas.read_csv("c:\week3data.csv", encoding="ISO-8859-1")
```

Comment: Without space it throws any different error    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1134, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1240, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1256, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1494, in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 42: invalid start byte

Comment: This is not an answer, it is a comment. I did not downvote, but this is probably why you received one. If code is fixed by simple typographical issue it is considered off topic, and should be closed, not answered. This is important because it perpetuates "low-quality" questions.

Comment: That is then not used correctly. It is easy for some to say that another person's problem is a "simple typographical issue " if you know the answer. The poster has shown effort and some people have a genuine interest in helping them solve their problem.  For reference : When should I vote down?

Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.